# Ruby on rails installation - Getting past welcome aboard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation

I have followed the instructions found at installrails.com however i am now at the page below.

[image]

I am not sure how to continue from here and have struggled to find any answers. If any one could help it would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: So, you've installed Rails and have created a sample app and shown that it works. "How to continue" has lots of answers. If you're looking to learn how to build an app, there are a number of tutorials to walk you through that process. One often-referenced one can be found here: https://www.railstutorial.org/

Comment: Check these links [Rails Cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/310-getting-started-with-rails?view=asciicast), [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)

Comment: Also note, that once you've created your model, controller and other stuff, your server will still default to the above page, unless you delete it or setup other routes. Make sure you go to localhost:3000/YourController or edit the default routing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hey Dont worry,** you are safely landed on the new Ruby On Rails Platform, of a new project that you have just created.

The shown page is the default display page for any Rails project we create, we have to design and set our on Index page or something instead of this page by creating new static or dynamic pages by creating new views, controllers and model associated with it. If you know the MVC frame work it is easy for you to begin with.

**If you are beginner to both MVC and Ruby on Rails, I suggest you to follow the railstutorial.org website to start with creating sample projects step by step, it is an easy and explained tutorial for beginners in Ruby On Rails by the Author Michael Hartl**

[Learn Web Development with Ruby On Rails: Michael Hartl](https://www.railstutorial.org/)

Comment: @CoderCalum : Hope my answer was helpful to you, if not just comment your doubts.

Answer (score 3):

You have successfully install rails on you machine, now create your model and controller and enjoy the beauty of rails. you can follow [rails tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/) for further reference.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change that page, just use the following code:

```
#config/routes.rb
root "application#index"

#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   def index
      #renders app/views/application/index.html.erb
   end
end

#app/views/application/index.html.erb
Hello world!
```

This will literally get you off that "Welcome Aboard" page and into a real Rails environment.

--

*However*...

If you want to get into the thick of Rails, here's a little bit more info on how to create a simple blog app. You may also wish to check out [Michael Hartl's "Rails Tutorial"](http://railstutorial.org):

1. You'll need a "model", "database" and "controller"
2. You'll need to learn about the backend structure of Rails

Here's how it works:

[image]

Rails is built around the [MVC (**M**odel **V**iew **C**ontroller)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) programming pattern. I won't go into details, but it means that whatever you develop in rails *needs* to have a `model`, `view` and `controller` action to support it.

Without that pattern, you'll not get anywhere with the system.

---

Thus, to make a simple blog app, you should create the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
root "posts#index"
resources :posts #-> url.com/posts/:id

#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
   before_action :find_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

   def index
      @posts = Post.all
   end

   def new
      @post = Post.new
   end

   def create
      @post = Post.new post_params
      @post.save
   end

   def show
   end

   def edit
   end

   def update
      redirect_to @post, notice: "Post Updated" if @post.update
   end

   def destroy
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "Post Destroyed" if @post.destroy
   end

   private

   def find_post
      @post = Post.find params[:id]
   end

   def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
   end
end
```

This will allow you to use the following views:

```
#app/views/posts/index.html.erb
<%= render @posts %>

#app/views/posts/show.html.erb
<%= render @post %>

#app/views/posts/edit.html.erb
<%= render "form", locals: {post: @post} %>

#app/views/posts/new.html.erb
<%= render "form", locals: {post: @post} %>

#app/views/posts/_post.html.erb
<%= post.title %>
<%= post.body %>

#app/views/posts/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for post do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :text %>
  <%= f.text_area :body %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

--

Finally, the model:

```
#app/models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

You'll also need a database table, which you create using [*migrations*](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html):

```
$ rails g migration CreatePosts

#db/migrate/create_posts_______.rb
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
      create_table :posts do |t|
         t.string :title
         t.text :body
         t.timestamps
      end
   end
end

$ rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to delete the public/index.html.  This happened to me when I copied a site into a blank website.